# How to TextTrimming with CharacterEllipsis effect in UWP toast notification?

Tags: uwp, toast

I am using [AdaptiveProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.adaptiveprogressbar?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) in my app for some reason. But in some case title of the progress bar is so long so I need to text trimming. But didn't found anything?

Answer (score 1):

> How to TextTrimming with CharacterEllipsis effect

Derive from testing, the max length of the  AdaptiveProgressBar title is 49. so we could cut the part of title that after 49 startindex.

```
var title = "Test long title";
int maxTitleLength = 49;
if (title.Length > maxTitleLength)
{
    var startIndex = maxTitleLength - 3;
    var sub = title.Remove(startIndex, title.Length - startIndex);
    title = sub + "...";
}


.AddProgressBar(new AdaptiveProgressBar().Title = title)
```

Comment: For multilingual app, it seems maxTitleLength will fail. As for different language, text length varies. Text with same length in different language may have different space to show in UI.

Comment: Yep, you are right, so you need detect maxTitleLength  manually, then pass different value. And you could also post this feature request with windows feed back hub app. and if the answer is helpful please consider mark it.